# Python creating objects in loop

Tags: python, class, loops, object

I know this question has been posted alot, however I cannot get my code to work. I have 2 classes, Main and PlayerLogic. I want to create multiple PlayerLogic objects within a loop, however I am getting this error "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

EDIT: I didnt mention that the classes are in different files with the exact same name of the class

```
class Main:

    import PlayerLogic


    numPlayers = int(input("How many player would you like? [excluding you]"))

    players = []
    for i in range(numPlayers):
        players.append(PlayerLogic(i))


class PlayerLogic:

    import random


    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = str(name)
```

Comment: Is PlayerLogic in its own file? You may have to call it like `players.append(PlayerLogic.PlayerLogic(i))`

Comment: But you `import PlayerLogic`?

Comment: `import PlayerLogic` is importing `PlayerLogic.py`. To import the class, try `from PlayerLogic import PlayerLogic`

Comment: ah! thank you so much, fixed it

Comment: Also - don't use capital letters in the name of a module! Call the module `playerlogic` and the class `PlayerLogic`.

Answer (score 1):

Your import is just importing the module not the PlayerLogic class.

You could do:

```
from PlayerLogic import PlayerLogic
```

Or keep the import as it is but then inside the loop use:

```
players.append(PlayerLogic.PlayerLogic(i))
```